# Can you explain me why I can't install rlang 0.4.10 on a R version 3.4.4?

Tags: r, rlang

When I try to install rlang 0.4.10 on an R version 3.4.4 I get an error message. But on the homepage they say that r version 3.3.0 is required.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/rlang_0.4.10.zip")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/R/win-library/3.4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/rlang_0.4.10.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: try downloading the zip file and installing it from the downloaded copy (`install.packages("rlang_0.4.10.zip", repos = NULL)`, where the zip file is in your working directory)

Comment: Thanks. With reinstalling an older version of Rtools (Rtools34) and reinstalling some components like dplyr, lifecircle and pillar everything works again with your hint.

Comment: You can go ahead and post that as an answer, if you think it will be useful to future readers ...